# Detect duplicates in JSON list and delete it

Tags: python, json, list, duplicates

I have a list with alterts, sometimes with duplicates in german and english language. I want to remove the duplicates from that list. So I want to say: if for an alert (which I detect as duplicate with the same timestamps for "start" and "end") is an duplicate in the list, remove this whole dataset-list from the alerts-list (which means "description", "event", "start",...): In this case the second list should be deleted:

```
{
"alerts": [
    {
        "description": "Es tritt leichter Frost auf.",
        "end": 1613379600,
        "event": "FROST",
        "lang": "de",
        "sender_name": "DWD / Nationales Warnzentrum Offenbach",
        "start": 1613322000
    },
    {
        "description": "There is a risk of frost",
        "end": 1613379600,
        "event": "frost",
        "lang": "en",
        "sender_name": "DWD / Nationales Warnzentrum Offenbach",
        "start": 1613322000
    },
    {
        "description": "There is a risk of wind gusts",
        "end": 1613408400,
        "event": "wind gusts",
        "lang": "en",
        "sender_name": "DWD / Nationales Warnzentrum Offenbach",
        "start": 1613336400
    }}
```

How can I do it in python and save the new alerts-list without duplicates?
I think it must be something like this (sorry for pseudo code, I can't transfer the already given examples, I am beginner...) please help! thx a lot!

```
for item in data['alerts']:
    if item['start'] == item['start'] and item['end'] == item['end']
        delete
```

So that I get this output:

```
 {
"alerts": [
    {
        "description": "Es tritt leichter Frost auf.",
        "end": 1613379600,
        "event": "FROST",
        "lang": "de",
        "sender_name": "DWD / Nationales Warnzentrum Offenbach",
        "start": 1613322000
    },
    {
        "description": "There is a risk of wind gusts",
        "end": 1613408400,
        "event": "wind gusts",
        "lang": "en",
        "sender_name": "DWD / Nationales Warnzentrum Offenbach",
        "start": 1613336400
    }}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your pseudocode  has the correct logic. Have you tried converting it to code ?

Comment: if 3 documents have the same timestamps which one do you want to keep?

Comment: never change a the length of a list (or any iterable) while you are iterating over it. what you can do is enumerate your list and remember the indices `for idx, item in enumerate(data['alerts']):` save the idx of the offending items and later iterate over that and and remove the relevent items from your data

Comment: the best case would be to keep this one with the "lang": "de" - but if not possible it's also ok to keep one with "lang": "en" - I also should detect if the "event" is the same (but difficult with german and english to match)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the filtering via dictionary comprehension:

```py
 data = {
"alerts": [
    {
        "description": "Es tritt leichter Frost auf.",
        "end": 1613379600,
        "event": "FROST",
        "lang": "de",
        "sender_name": "DWD / Nationales Warnzentrum Offenbach",
        "start": 1613322000
    },
    {
        "description": "There is a risk of frost",
        "end": 1613379600,
        "event": "frost",
        "lang": "en",
        "sender_name": "DWD / Nationales Warnzentrum Offenbach",
        "start": 1613322000
    },
    {
        "description": "There is a risk of wind gusts",
        "end": 1613408400,
        "event": "wind gusts",
        "lang": "en",
        "sender_name": "DWD / Nationales Warnzentrum Offenbach",
        "start": 1613336400
    }]}

filtered = {(entry["start"], entry["end"]): entry for entry in reversed(data["alerts"])}

data["alerts"] = list(filtered.values())
```

This approach utilizes the fact that duplicated dictionary keys are overwritten with the last entry.
Remove the `reversed()` if you'd like to keep the last duplicated entry instead of the first one

Comment: it works! I will test it for some other examples, maybe it is possible to to decide for this one of the two duplicates with the "lang": "de", if existing. But I was looking for exactly that filter-function, thx a lot!

Comment: @VishalSingh, the original task was to leave only the first value amongst all duplicates. Since dict keys overwrite in a "last in" fashion, to get the first entries from a duplicated set, the `reversed` is needed. As in my answer, it could be removed if the author doesn't care which of the duplicates gets stored

Comment: @buran, yeah, I haven't included that case
Adding `reversed(sorted(lambda entry: entry["lang"], ...))` could help, but what if there are other languages ?

Comment: @Icebreaker454 Actually, my comment was not correct and that is why I deleted it - because you don't sort, just reverse. In this case you are dependent on the original order and also your argument about other languages holds also in this case. But that's up to OP to concider.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the input list by lang in reverse order - `en` will come before `de`, then make a dict, where key is tuple `(start, end)` and use the `dict.values()`. Because `de` will come after `en` if there are alerts with same key start, end, de will update the value for the key.

```
data = {
"alerts": [
    {
        "description": "Es tritt leichter Frost auf.",
        "end": 1613379600,
        "event": "FROST",
        "lang": "de",
        "sender_name": "DWD / Nationales Warnzentrum Offenbach",
        "start": 1613322000
    },
    {
        "description": "There is a risk of wind gusts",
        "end": 1613408400,
        "event": "wind gusts",
        "lang": "en",
        "sender_name": "DWD / Nationales Warnzentrum Offenbach",
        "start": 1613336400
    }]}

unique = {(item['start'], item['end']):item for item in
           sorted(data['alerts'], key=lambda x: x['lang'], reverse=True)}
data['alerts'] = sorted(unique.values(), key=lambda x: (x['start'], x['end']))
```

output

```
{
    "alerts": [
        {
            "description": "Es tritt leichter Frost auf.",
            "end": 1613379600,
            "event": "FROST",
            "lang": "de",
            "sender_name": "DWD / Nationales Warnzentrum Offenbach",
            "start": 1613322000
        },
        {
            "description": "There is a risk of wind gusts",
            "end": 1613408400,
            "event": "wind gusts",
            "lang": "en",
            "sender_name": "DWD / Nationales Warnzentrum Offenbach",
            "start": 1613336400
        }
    ]
}
```

not sure if you need result sorted by time, so you can removed that part

Comment: this also solves my question, but I can't give two "Checks" thx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can group all the similar timestamps using [**`itertools.groupby`** [Python-docs]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and then select the document with English language.

```
from itertools import groupby

data["alerts"] = sorted(data["alerts"], key=lambda x: (x["end"], x["start"]))
data["alerts"] = [
    g
    for key, group in groupby(data["alerts"], key=lambda x: (x["end"], x["start"]))
    for g in group
    if g["lang"] == "en"  # change accordingly
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping the known timestamps in a list then in upcoming elements, check if it is already visited, then ignore.

```py
data = {
"alerts": [
    {
        "description": "Es tritt leichter Frost auf.",
        "end": 1613379600,
        "event": "FROST",
        "lang": "de",
        "sender_name": "DWD / Nationales Warnzentrum Offenbach",
        "start": 1613322000
    },
    {
        "description": "There is a risk of frost",
        "end": 1613379600,
        "event": "frost",
        "lang": "en",
        "sender_name": "DWD / Nationales Warnzentrum Offenbach",
        "start": 1613322000
    },
    {
        "description": "There is a risk of wind gusts",
        "end": 1613408400,
        "event": "wind gusts",
        "lang": "en",
        "sender_name": "DWD / Nationales Warnzentrum Offenbach",
        "start": 1613336400
    }]}

visited_timestamp = []
output = []
for each_message in data['alerts']:
    if (each_message['end'], each_message['start']) in visited_timestamp:
        pass # don't do anything
    else:
        output.append(each_message)
        visited_timestamp.append((each_message['end'], each_message['start']))
        
data['alerts'] = output
print(data)
```

```
{
'alerts':
 [
{'description': 'Es tritt leichter Frost auf.', 'end': 1613379600, 'event': 'FROST', 'lang': 'de', 'sender_name': 'DWD / Nationales Warnzentrum Offenbach', 'start': 1613322000}, 

{'description': 'There is a risk of wind gusts', 'end': 1613408400, 'event': 'wind gusts', 'lang': 'en', 'sender_name': 'DWD / Nationales Warnzentrum Offenbach', 'start': 1613336400}
]
}
```

Comment: You mess up the timestamp pairing. In the question it's specified that the timestamps should match in an AND fashion